# Any other possible way for XML text insertion in python?

Tags: python, xml, text, insert, elementtree

My problem is not finding the word "my" in the ex

Here's my snippet:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import re

def prettify(elem):
  rs = et.tostring(elem,encoding='utf-8')
  rp = minidom.parseString(rs)
  return rp.toprettyxml(indent="  ")

root=et.Element('my_root')

et.SubElement(root, 'my_element')
root[0].text = 'hello my world'
print(prettify(root))

a,b = re.search("my", root[0].text).span()
print(f'position of \'my\': [{a}:{b}]')

t = root[0].text
l = [t[:a], '<red>', t[a:b], '</red>', t[b:]]
print(l)

root[0].text = ''.join(l)
print(prettify(root))
```

My problem is how to insert the XML correctly.

The last output of print(prettify(root)) shows now

```
<my_element>hello &lt;red&gt;my&lt;/red&gt; world</my_element>
```

in the relevant line.That's not what I want.

I want

```
<my_element>hello <red>my</red> world</my_element>
```

instead. Is that possible at all?

If yes, then tell me how?

Comment: it is not clear what is your input and what is the desired output. please explain

Comment: I have edited with better explanation. Please check now. Thanks

Comment: do you want to compose the XML `<my_element>hello <red>my</red> world</my_element>` progrmaticaly?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for that

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do that

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = Element('my_element')
root.text = 'hello'
child = SubElement(root, 'red')
child.text = 'my'
child.tail = 'world'
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<my_element>hello<red>my</red>world</my_element>
```